# How do I change message.guild.channels.some in order to make it to work in V12?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, compatibility

I try to put `message.guild.channels.some` in my `Discord.JS V12` bot but its not working. Does somebody know to what this code changed to? I tried to research on Google but nothing ever made my problem to solve.

Thank you `PLAMSMA chicken`. You fixed my problem.
The solution is:
`message.guild.channels.cache.some`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[v12] Methods accessing cached data are now found on the cache

```
- guild.roles.get("id")
+ guild.roles.cache.get("id")
- message.guild.channels.some
+ message.guild.channels.cache.some
```

This is the case for any structure relying on cached data, the most likely affected parts of your code are the Collection methods and properties `(.size, .has(), .get(), .filter(), .map(), .find(), .forEach(), .reduce(), .sort(), .some())`

Read more about here: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache

Comment: If I show you a piece of my code, will you fix it? The rest of the code is hidden/not coded.